Prefect with Google Cloud Run: Creating a New Execution ID for Each Flow in a Single Job
I am currently using Prefect cloud to orchestrate different tasks, and I am deploying these tasks as jobs on Google Cloud Run using the CloudRun Push workpool.
Here's the situation I am facing: every time a flow is run, it creates a new job on Cloud Run. However, this is not the behavior I want. Instead, I would like to have a single job for each deployment, having the deployment name, and each flow run should create a new execution ID within that job.
I’ve looked through the Prefect and Google Cloud Run documentation but haven’t found a clear way to achieve this.
Does anyone have experience with this kind of setup or could point me in the right direction? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I tried to use the following configuration in prefect.yaml:
  infra_overrides:
    env:
      PREFECT_FLOW_NAME: prefect-daily-testrun
  infrastructure:
    job_variable_name: PREFECT_FLOW_NAME

but the result is the same: a new job is created having the name of the flow.

Can you elaborate on your issue by sharing the steps you are following about your infrastructure to replicate the issue and the document you are following?

well, I just create a new flow, and a work pool, then I use prefect cli to create a deployment for that flow, and connect it to that work pool. After setting up the git pull step, everything goes as expected: I run the deployment and a new job in CloudRun is created.
If I run everything again, another job is created, but what I need is to create a new execution ID for the previous job, as it is the same flow running.
Here's the documentation:
https://docs.prefect.io/2.10.21/guides/cloud-run-push-work-pools/
